# Can't access Activity methods from AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android

When I extend AppCompatActivity I cannot use the methods from Activity such as finish() and setTheme() although the Android developer page says I should be able to use them.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.0'

}
```

Here is my code that is giving me errors:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
        if (Sections.isLocked(this)) {
            Data.showSectionLocked(Data.last);
            finish();
        } else {
            Data.last = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to fix this?

EDIT: It seems like this is an issue with android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.

Upon Ctrl+clicking on AppCompatActivity I noticed that it cannot extend Fragment Activity for some reason:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brRf5.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj2i0.png)

Comment: please post the error message (LogCat)

Comment: "Cannot resolve method 'finish()' "

Comment: I cannot get a logcat because it does not compile. If I extend Activity directly these errors go away, however when I go back to AppCompatActivity they return.

Comment: @LinX64 I added some more information to the post, could you take a look?

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong btw, weird, i'll check if i had any ideas, i'll share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by uninstalling Android Studio, removing all directories/files associated with it, restarting my computer, and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue and fix for me it was changed buildToolsVersion to "23.0.3" in build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

[**AppCompatActivity**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) inherit from **FragmentActivity**, **FragmentActivity** inherit from Activity. So you can use *finish()* without any issue.

Checkout you import correct **AppCompatActivity** and rebuild your project.

Comment: Added my build.gradle

Comment: You are right, I _should_ be able to use finish() but for some reason I cannot.